# Datetime tuple to seconds tuple

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

What's the best way to convert a tuple of 90'000 `datetime.datetime` objects which I get from the query below to a tuple of seconds since midnight?

e.g. 2014-06-13 10:33:20 should become 38000 (10*3600+33*60+20)

```
query = """
        SELECT timestamp, value
        FROM measurements
        WHERE timestamp BETWEEN %s AND %s AND sensor = %s 
        """
cursor.execute(query, (start, stop, sensor))
row = cursor.fetchall()
timestamp, value=zip(*row)
```

Comment: Updated question - it's the number of seconds since midnight.

Comment: have you thought about time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function to convert to seconds and then use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

# Generate some random datetime objects.
d = [datetime.today() + timedelta(seconds=i*600) for i in range(10)]

def dt_to_seconds(dt):
    return 3600*dt.hour + 60*dt.minute + dt.second

s = tuple([dt_to_seconds(i) for i in d])

print(s)
# (35545, 36145, 36745, 37345, 37945, 38545, 39145, 39745, 40345, 40945)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider z consists of list of your time values  then `map()`

```
z=["10:33:20","4:50:22"]  

print map(lambda x:int(x.split(':')[0])*3600+int(x.split(':')[1])*60+int(x.split(':')[2]),z)
#output[38000, 17422]
```

Comment: No need to parse strings here ... OP already said that it's a `datetime.datetime` object.  The format is just the default format of `datetime.datetime.__str__`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to select the value in seconds to begin with:

```
query = """
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,DATE(timestamp),timestamp), value
    FROM measurements
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN %s AND %s AND sensor = %s 
    """
```

the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) is there so you'll get only the time part in seconds and not the entire date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%H:%i:%s')) AS SECOND
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Check [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) and [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function

Comment: I wonder which is faster - your approach or the one I listed below